# Delete files from folder except one in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to add a script which will delete files from directory before installation of new version. I need save from directory one catalog - /logs and all files inside ( inside we have *.log and *.zg files)

Ive created this line : `find /directory/path/* ! -name 'logs' -type d,f -exec rm -r -v {} +` 
But in Debian 11 Its cleaning also my files inside of catalog log.
Do you know what can be a reason ?

It works on zsh on macbook m1 and is not cleaning my log catalog.

Take Care : )

Expectation
bash script which delete all catalogs and files from given directory EXCEPT one catalog /log and all files inside ( inside we have *.log and *.zg files) .

Comment: thats one line doing way too much if you can possibly break it up that would be much better. for a million reasons. one of them would be to allow you to analyze whats going on after each command. now you just run the whole thing and if it doesnt work correctly..

Comment: I can't figure out what you want and can't figure out how to ask you for it, but I'm inclined to agree with @john-jones in that you're trying to be too clever. You're far better off being explicit with what you delete rather than with what you'd prefer to not delete.

Comment: Rather than `find /dir/path/*`, which passes all the names in `/dir/path` as arguments to `find`, you probably want `find /dir/path` (without the glob).  But that's not the main problem.

Comment: @md well just look at that comand. like, wtf. but i guess the find command has tried to grow like crazy and taken on that bloat thing. if u could possibly solve 1 10th of the problem with some text thing. then continue. then solve 1 10th again. then 1 10 again etc. in unix we are always piping, using |. then each command is making the problem a tiny bit smaller. then if something goes wrong u can always back track throug each and every piping.

Comment: Thank you Guys - I will reconstruct this to smaller pieces and give you some feedback. Meantime if anyone have some idea that is also super.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
$ find . ! -name logs
.
./logs/a
./foo
./foo/a
```

The issue here is that although the directory `logs` matches the primary `-name logs`, the name `a` in `logs` does not. So find operates on that file.   Rather than negating the `-name` primary, you want to match the `logs` directory and `prune` that from the find:

```
$ find . -name logs -prune -o -print
.
./foo
./foo/a
```

Also note that instead of `find /directory/path/* ...`, you almost certainly want `find /directory/path ...`.  There's no need to pass all of the names in `/directory/path` as arguments to `find`, and indeed that is ... weird.  Just pass the top level dir and let `find` handle the tree descent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe extended globbing.

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -frv /directory/path/!(logs)
```

Comment: This one is not working on Debian - Its deleting whole /log catalog with all files inside. :|